# No autocompletion with the ipdb prompt when using Spyder

Tags: python, ipython, spyder, ipdb

I'm using Spyder for my python programming.
I'm having a problem when I use the debugfile (F7) command/function.
Once in the ipdb prompt I have no autocompletion and the up arrow action (for the history of commands) does not work.

When I'm using IPython on the terminal (I'm on MacOS) everything works fine.

I have installed Spyder, ipdb, and IPython using macport.
When I've tried installing with anaconda, the same problem occurs.

Do you have any idea of what's happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) This is a limitation of the new, kernel-based architecture of IPython. We're planning to create a workaround over it and also significantly improve our debugging facilities next year, as can be seen in our [Roadmap](https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/wiki/Roadmap).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answer and for the great job. Spyder is very usefull!!

Comment: The roadmap can be now found here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Roadmap

Comment: Would it help if there was a terminal widget in Spyder ? `ipdb` works great in terminal where it supports auto-complete and command history.

Comment: Any news on that? I have installed the latest Spyder 3.0.0 beta4 but in ipdb the autocomplete still does not work and the history neither.

Comment: @OldrichSvec, sorry, we haven't made any progress in that front. This is something we need to solve along with the Jupyter guys :-)